# VB, creating a save file menu

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible with VB.2010 to create a 'save' file option that will save current app settings to a file and then be able to 'open' those setting. basically I am after implementing the traditional save, open feature in my drop down task bar.

When I say settings I mean a load of text box contents etc

Comment: Yeps, that's certainly possible. You can try something and if it doesn't work, we will try to help you

Comment: Do you want to roll your own configuration settings or the existing xml config file?

Comment: You could just use a .settings file or do write something custom if you wanted, of course.

Comment: well ideally id like the user to be able to save the contents under a save name so that they can recall them for future purposes. T

Comment: how does one do the system file, can you have multiple saves to the one file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store it in a text file, if it's not secure/confidential information.

This is just an example:

```
    ' For own file name or save place...

    Dim sfd As New SaveFileDialog
    sfd.ShowDialog()
    Dim myPath As String = sfd.FileName

    ' Replace "My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "\NAME_OF_FILE.txt" with "myPath"

    ' To save
    FileOpen(1, My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "\NAME_OF_FILE.txt", OpenMode.Output)
    PrintLine(1, TextBox1.Text)
    PrintLine(1, TextBox2.Text)
    ' And so on...
    FileClose(1)

    ' To load
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "\NAME_OF_FILE.txt") Then
        FileOpen(1, My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "\NAME_OF_FILE.txt", OpenMode.Input)
        TextBox1.Text = LineInput(1)
        TextBox2.Text = LineInput(1)
        ' And so on...
        FileClose(1)
    End If
```

Remember to always close the file, otherwise you'll get memory leaks and all sorts of nasty stuff =P

You can use `FreeFile()` to get the next free file number, comes in use when opening multiple files...

This is a simple method, I'm sure you can use this as a template and implement it for your own use.

Hope it helps

Comment: cool thanks, yeah that is really handy for the time being until i can get to grips with how to implement a open/save with a prompt for file name etc. Would be good to be able to be able to manually select save location from within app but from what i gather from previous posts there are restrictions, am I right/wrong?

Comment: In Windows Vista+ there is UAC, so there are some restrictions as to where you can create files/folders. For example, creating a folder in the `Program Files` directory, will require administrator privileges, but if you run your app as an admin you can create folders/files in those "restricted" places. Please see my edit for using own file name, and own save places.

Comment: thanks very much. i get the prompt for the save and location but under but the save file type box is empty and when i save a name it doesn't save anything. any ideas?

Comment: i have just run it on a test project so it is near enough what you provided, here is:

Comment: Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim sfd As New SaveFileDialog
        sfd.ShowDialog()
        Dim myPath As String = sfd.FileName
        FileOpen(1, "mypath", OpenMode.Output)
        PrintLine(1, RichTextBox1.Text)
        FileClose(1)

Comment: Heheh, on your code "mypath" is as a string, I mean type `myPath`without the quotes. The SaveFileDialog returns the path that you selected, including the file name typed. I just store that in a String variable called `myPath` then I pass `myPath` to the `FileOpen` function. Please try to understand the code.